# How to take the the flow of intro.js inside a datatable rows and columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

[After I click on (May I Help-Click) Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idSq8.png)

[It goes to first step that is fine, but i want now that next step it must go to the row and higligt columns step by step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP82T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it, you need to specify the class attribute of the div to class="introjs-nextbutton". If anyone know other way of doing it, welcome in advance.

```
<div data-step="2" data-intro="Third" class="introjs-nextbutton" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the `data-step` attribute to your column specifying the step number.

```
<td data-step="2">
```

This will used by Intro Js to navigate to next step.